# Why use pass instead of something shorter like 0 in Python?

Tags: python, coding-style

Why use `pass` instead of something shorter like `0` in Python?

E.g.:

```
for i in range(10): pass
```

vs.

```
for i in range(10): 0
```

The only two upsides of using `pass` are:

1. If using the Python interactive interpreter, it will output `0`
2. `pass` is more understandable than `0`

Is there any other reason behind the use of `pass`?

Comment: Because readibilty is more important than length.

Comment: @Delgan sure, I am looking for other potential reasons, as stated in the question.

Comment: None that I know of, though you could try to `timeit` to be sure. But, anyway, you see the two upsides, there is no downside, so I guess that's enough justification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer: **It's probably just there for readability.**

I dug through an [old version of python's source code (version 0.9.1)](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/src/) and found this in a file called doc/tut.tex:

```
 \subsubsection{Pass Statements}

 The {\tt pass} statement does nothing.
 It can be used when a statement is required syntactically but the
 program requires no action.
 For example:
 \bcode\begin{verbatim}
 >>> while 1:
 ...       pass # Busy-wait for keyboard interrupt
 ...
 \end{verbatim}\ecode
```

And then this reference to it (without much other documentation) in a file called src/graminit.c:

```
   {269, "pass_stmt", 0, 3, states_13,
    "\000\000\000\000\002\000\000\000\000\000\000\000"},
```

which I guess is just adding `pass` to a pretty base-level vocabulary of python.

this as well, in src/compile.c:

```
   case pass_stmt:
           break;
```

and an incredibly cool file called src/Grammar which makes some references to it and has a changelog at the top which labels itself "Grammar for Python, version 4" but logs no changes to the pass_stmt.

And I couldn't find anything else.  So it seems like `pass` has been in python since forever, and the only documentation from the beginning of the python project says that it 'does nothing.'  So I think we can conclude that it's to do nothing, readably.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the [Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/), you can see some reasons;

- Readability counts.
- Explicit is better than implicit.
- In the face of ambiguity, refuse the temptation to guess.

There is no mistaking what `pass` is. 
While a 0 could mean an integer or a null operation depending on the context. That makes the code harder to read and ambiguous.